# Spring bean from test profile in JUnit 5 test class is not injected

Tags: java, spring, configuration, mockito

I would like to use in my **jUnit 5** test class

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@ActiveProfiles("localtest")
class WorkreportDbRepositoryTest {

  @Autowired
  private SystemPriceSettingService systemPriceSettingService;

// the rest omitted .... 

}
```

a bean created in configuration for testing environment:

```
@Profile("localtest")
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

  @Bean
  public SystemPriceSettingService systemPriceSettingService(){
    return new MemoryPriceSettingService();
  }

}
```

But the `SystemPriceSettingService` bean is **not** injected. What's wrong with my setup?

Comment: You forgot to annotate it with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use  a JUnit Runner that is Spring aware. So no Spring context is created.
You should replace it the annotations on the test class such as :

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("localtest")
class WorkreportDbRepositoryTest { ...}
```

And add this dependency to be able to use `SpringExtension` :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.0</version> <!-- your mockito version-->
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```